# Multiple layouts in ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

Just started Ruby on Rails yesterday. In my layouts/application.html.erb i have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Coming from php ->codeigniter background, i'm assuming render is similar to $this->load->view(''); in codeigniter.
Although this works fine, i would like to have multiple application layout files e.g

1. layout/application default
2. layout/application fullwidth(for fullwidth pages)
3. and so on..

In codeigniter you simply declare which of the templates/layout files you wish to use but as ruby on rails is a bit magical(It does a lot of things for you), i'm assuming it calls the application layout by default. I was wondering if there's a way to choose what layout file i want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the [`layout`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Layouts/ClassMethods.html#method-i-layout) method.

[This Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) will help you, specifically [Finding Layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#finding-layouts). I'd provide more detail here, but the previously mentioned documentation and guide provide more than enough examples and usage instruction.

Answer (score 15):

@Deefour gave the right resources, here is a nice quick example on how you can implement this in Rails 4.

In a controller you can specify where you want to fetch what layout for a certain action and have very nicely fine grained control over which layout is used.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  layout "fullwidth", except: [:index, :faqs]

  def popout
    # Render this action with specific layout
    render layout: "popout"
    #renders with views/layouts/popout.html.erb
  end

  def index
    #renders with views/layouts/application.html.erb
  end

  def about_us
    #renders with views/layouts/fullwidth.html.erb
  end

  def team
    #renders with views/layouts/fullwidth.html.erb
  end

  def logo
    #renders with views/layouts/fullwidth.html.erb
  end

  def faqs
    #renders with views/layouts/application.html.erb
  end
end
```

***application.html.erb*** is the rails standard layout file. I assume it is present, and it is the default fallback!

Comment: All not defined will fallback to application.html.erb?

Comment: ```application.html.erb``` is the rails standard layout file. I assume it is present, and it is the default fallback, yes.