# How to integrate 2 themes in 1 rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation, activeadmin

I have a rails app, and I want to create the Admin interface but I DON'T want to use ActiveAdmin gem.

We are using Zurb Foundation, and I want to use [this](https://dresssed.com/themes/ives) bootstrap admin theme.

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to use 2 different skins themes in a rails app? So for example I want to render a different theme for all the routes with the namespace `/admin`. If possible, how to do this?
2. If the above is possible would it have issues since the main theme is on Zurb Foundation and the admin theme is on Bootstrap?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple layouts in ror](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228228/multiple-layouts-in-ror)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would require two layouts, each would point to it's own css.  The frameworks won't overlap and should work fine.